# Lagrange's Multiplier

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

What is the distance of the farthest point lying on the curve $2x^2 ＋ 6xy ＋ 5y^2 ＝1$ from the origin? It can be solved by polar coordinates but I was trying to do it by Lagrange multipliers by this method $x^2＋y^2+ c(2x^2 ＋ 6xy ＋ 5y^2 -1)$, but I am not getting any maximum answer from it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Make life simpler and maximize $d^2=x^2+y^2$

Comment: It is not so simple, you have a condition $$2x^2+6xy+5y^2-1=0$$

Comment: Almost by definition, a maximum (or, for that matter, minimum) of the function $d(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ under the condition $2 x^2 + 6 x y + 5y^2 = 1$ is the same as a maximum of the function $d^2(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ under the condition $2 x^2 + 6 x y + 5y^2 = 1$ (since $\xi \mapsto \xi^2$ is (strictly) increasing on $[0, \infty)$).

Answer (score 1):

Work with the square of the distance, that is, let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. So, you get the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2x=\lambda(4x+6y)\\2y=\lambda(6x+10y)\\2x^2+6xy+10y^2=1\end{array}\right.$$The first two equation form a system of linear equations dependent upon $\lambda$. So, choose $\lambda$ such that the determinant of the matrix of the coefficients of the system is $0$; otherwise, the only solution will be $(0,0)$, which is not a solution of the third equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the formula $$d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ where $$2x^2+6xy+5y^2=1$$
Use the function
$$F(x.y.\lambda)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\lambda(2x^2+6xy+5y^2-1)$$
and differentiate with respect to $x,y,\lambda$
or you plug $$y=\frac{1}{5}(-3x-\sqrt{5-x^2})$$
or $$y=\frac{1}{5}(-3x+\sqrt{5-x^2})$$
in your objective function and you will get a Problem in only one variable.

Comment: But how do I maximise this by lagrange's multiplier. method

Comment: Do I need to put root over x²+y² term because maximising (x²+y²)½ is similar to maximising x²+y²

Comment: yes this is true, but you must Substitute $$y^2$$ by your condition.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x^2+6xy+5y^2=1$$ is the graph of an ellipse centered at the origin with the vertices along the eigenvectors of the matrix, $$ A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\3&5\end {pmatrix}$$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are  $$\frac {7\pm \sqrt 45}{2}$$

Thus the maximum distance from the origin is $$(\frac {2}{   7- \sqrt 45})^2 \approx 46.97$$

Comment: how did you find vertices of the ellipse please explain

Comment: Vertices are the endpoints are the eigenvectors in the rotated system.  We do not need the vertices to find the maximum distance all we need 
 is the  semi major axis length. The new equation has the form $\lambda _1 ^2 {x^*}^2 + \lambda _2 ^2 {y^*}^2 =1.$

Comment: Sir I don't know much about eigenvectors but from what I can understand is that you rotated the axis of the ellipse along x axis and y axis and then used the standard form of ellipse to find semi major axis. If that is correct please tell me how did you rotated the axis to obtain standard form

Comment: You find the matrix of eigenvectors and  the transformation is the result of multiplication by that matrix. It is called the principal axis theorem. You may google it and read more about it.